# Inject string parameter with specific value to all types

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Given

```
interface IFoo ...
class MyClass1 : IFoo
{
    public MyClass1(string id) ...
}

class MyClass2 : IFoo
{
    public MyClass2(string id) ...
}
//new classes will be added
```

When I resolve the classes:

```
UnityContainer container = ...;
container.Resolve(typeThatImplementsIFoo);
```

Then how can I setup UnityContainer so that it injects value `"123"` to any ctor parameter `"string id"` when resolving any class that implements IFoo?

Comment: The answer to your question is depending on what kind of value "123" is. In case "123" is a runtime value (something that might change from request to request) the answer is: [change your design](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). If "123" is a configuration value (or anything that won't change after the application was started), you can use a lambda to make the registration.

Comment: Im using this in unit tests and it is constant. Basically I'm trying to write generic unit test that test all implementations of IFoo. I abused UnityContainer as an generic instatiator

Comment: Ah, you are using Unity as an [Auto-mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that if you write a custom `BuilderStrategy` that will override input parameter in constructor for your classes.

I wrote a test classes for simplifying. They are the similar to your classes:

```
    public interface IFoo {}

    public class MyClass : IFoo
    {
        public string Id;

        public MyClass(string id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass2 : IFoo
    {
        public string Id;

        public MyClass2(string id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

They are the custom `BuilderStrategy` and the custom `UnityContainerExtension`:

```
    public class UnityExtension<TInterface> : UnityContainerExtension
    {
        private readonly string _paramName;
        private readonly object _paramValue;

        public UnityExtension(string paramName, object paramValue)
        {
            _paramName = paramName;
            _paramValue = paramValue;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            var strategy = new BuildStrategy<TInterface>(_paramName, _paramValue);
            Context.Strategies.Add(strategy, UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
        }
    }

    public class BuildStrategy<TInterface> : BuilderStrategy
    {
        private readonly string _paramName;
        private readonly object _paramValue;

        public BuildStrategy(string paramName, object paramValue)
        {
            _paramName = paramName;
            _paramValue = paramValue;
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            if (typeof(TInterface).IsAssignableFrom(context.OriginalBuildKey.Type))
            {
                context.AddResolverOverrides(new ParameterOverride(_paramName, _paramValue));
            }
        }
    }
```

You need the custom `UnityContainerExtension`, because you cannot access to the collection of `BuilderStrategy` from `UnityContainer` without reflection.

And so you only need to add this extension to `UnityContainer` and try to resolve a type that you want:

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddExtension(new UnityExtension<IFoo>("id", "123"));

    var class1 = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
    var class2 = container.Resolve<MyClass2>();

    // show 123
    Console.WriteLine(class1.Id);  

    // show 123
    Console.WriteLine(class2.Id);
```